# How retrieve only filename from save file dialog

Tags: c#, winforms, savefiledialog, filedialog

I have a save file dialog and i want to get only the filename entered. Equivalent for

```
    openfiledialog.SafeFileName;
```

Save file dialog has no `SafeFileName` Property and `FileName` returns both filename, path and extension. Pls how do i extract only file name.

Comment: Consider using search engines first... [c# retrieve only filename from file path](http://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+retrieve+only+filename+from+file+path) gives pretty decent shot at answer.

Comment: @cody-gray: this should not be marked as a duplicate. The linked question is for OpenFileDialog and this is SaveFileDialog. The accepted answer for the linked duplicate will not work for SaveFileDialog.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you want the filename **with** extension use `Path.GetFileName()`. If you want it **without** the extension as well use `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension()`.

```
public void Test(string fileName)
{
    string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(fileName);
    string filename_with_ext = Path.GetFileName(fileName);
    string filename_without_ext = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName);
    string ext_only = Path.GetExtension(fileName);
}
```

See MSDN for further details, especially the `Path` class which has a number of useful methods:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO.Path_methods.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Also found another solution to my problem

```
    FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(saveFileDialog1.FileName);
    string text = fi.Name;
```